# Tensorflow .batch does not separate tensors correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-preprocessing

I have an array of shape (1, 6354944)

```
array([[ 9.15527344e-05, -6.10351562e-05,  6.10351562e-05, ...,
     1.01928711e-02,  7.92236328e-02, -2.69470215e-02]])
```

And converted them to tensor slices

```
stream = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(reshaped_data)
```

But when I batch them

```
seqs = stream.batch(1000, drop_remainder=True)
```

It returns

```
<BatchDataset shapes: (1000, 6354944), types: tf.float64>
```

When it's supposed to have a shape of

```
(1000, 6354)
```

Comment: a batch of 1000 is too large! Do you want that all your dataset be ONE big batch of 1000 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape your data before creating the dataset :

```
r = tf.reshape(a[ : , :6354000 ], (1000, 6354))
stream = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(r)
seqs = stream.batch(1000) #(1000,6354)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set

drop_remainder=False

to produce an smaller batch as stated in the docs:

Batch:

batch(
batch_size, drop_remainder=False, num_parallel_calls=None, deterministic=None
)

The components of the resulting element will have an additional outer dimension, which will be batch_size (or N % batch_size for the last element if batch_size does not divide the number of input elements N evenly and drop_remainder is False). If your program depends on the batches having the same outer dimension, you should set the drop_remainder argument to True to prevent the smaller batch from being produced.